# jQuery kills other function

Tags: jquery, conflict

I have a div with id='user'. If a guest is visiting there is a login form and register form. I'm using tabs to switch between login and register forms.

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.box a').livequery('click', function(e){
        switch_tabs(jQuery(this));
    });
    switch_tabs(jQuery('.defaulttab'));


    function switch_tabs(obj){
        jQuery('.box-content').hide();
        jQuery('.box a').removeClass('selected');
        var id = obj.attr("rel");

        jQuery('#'+id).show();
        obj.addClass("selected"); }
});
```

After wher press login or registration button with the jquery load function `(jQuery('#user').load(location.href+' #user'))` I reload the div tag (#user)

and then there is just a logout button. When the button is pressed, it destroys the session in php and reloads the #user div

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#off').livequery('click', function(e){
        jQuery('.loader').html('<img src="img/loader.gif" />').show();
        jQuery.post('process/logoff.php', null, function(data){
            jQuery('#user').load(location.href+' #user');
            jQuery('.loader').hide();
        });
    });
});
```

After reload my `switch_tab` function will not work and shows both (register and login divs).  Why would this be happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you check your JS console for errors?  I'd venture a guess that some JS error is keeping your code from running and thus why you're seeing both.

Comment: Yes, but there whas no errors!

Comment: Are you sure that switch_tab isn't working and not something else?  for example you said they both show, but when you click on a `.box a` it should show/hide divs.  Does it?  If not, does it render an error?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newer version of jQuery, shouldn't you be using: `.on()` ?

Also wouldn't you want to reference the 'id' instead of 'rel' ?:

```
var id = obj.attr("id");
```

If you are trying to reference the id of what you are showing.